# Compress space of hidden fields within the master page Adobe Forms SAP

Tags: javascript, forms, adobe, abap

I want to hide a text field between "fournisseur" and "adresse". I have used a flowed subform as a container and the docready event because my textfield is in the master page.

This is working good in PDF preview but in the generated PDF file, the textfield is hidden but its occupied space is still there. How to compress the space?

javascript code:

```
if( this.rawValue == null)
                {
                    this.presence = "hidden";
                }
```

Preview:

[image]

Generated PDF file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that can be resolved by putting this in the content area and not in the master page. Make 2 master pages and in the first you define your header information inside your content area. Make sure the first master page where your content area is located is only shown for the first page.